# connect to ESP8266 module

Tags: c#, localhost, ip-address, tcpclient, esp8266

I have an ESP8266 wifi module.
I want to establish a connection between the my windows form App and the module through the following code.

```
                try
                {
                    Board_WiFi = new TcpClient();                    
                    IPAddress[] ipAddress = Dns.GetHostAddresses("192.168.4.1");//ESP8266 IP:192.168.4.1:384
                    IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress[0], 384);
                    Board_WiFi.Connect(endPoint);
                    Thread thread1 = new Thread(() => ReciveData(Board_WiFi, "XYZ", tokenSource.Token));
                    thread1.IsBackground = true;
                    thread1.Start();                    
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Board_WiFi.Close();
                    Board_WiFi = null;                    
                    MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());                    
                } 

private void ReciveData(TcpClient tcpClient, string MachinName, CancellationToken token)
        {
            byte[] buff = new byte[1];
            try
            {
                while (tcpClient.Connected)
                {                    
                    if (tcpClient.Client.Receive(buff, SocketFlags.Peek) != 0)
                    {
                        if (tcpClient.Client.Available > 0 && tcpClient != null)
                        {
                            string fff = tcpClient.Available.ToString();
                            NetworkStream stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
                            byte[] msg = new byte[tcpClient.Available];
                            string strReciveData;
                            stream.Read(msg, 0, tcpClient.Available);
                            strReciveData = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(msg);
                            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                            {
                                {
                                    richTextBoxPM.Text = MachinName + "<<" + strReciveData + "\n";                                    
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    else break;
                }                           
                Board_WiFi.Close();
                Board_WiFi = null;                
            }
            catch
            {
                tcpClient.Close();
                tcpClient = null;                
                toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Connection Time Out";
                btnConnect.Text = "Connect";
                toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "DisConnect";
            }
        }
```

My problem is in the second line of the try block.
When I try to connect to the module with code `IPAddress[] ipAddress = Dns.GetHostAddresses("192.168.4.1");`, the connection is established, but when the connection is disconnected from the ESP8266, I cannot detect the lack of connection.
But when I use the code

```
IPAddress ipAddress = Dns.GetHostEntry("192.168.4.1").AddressList[0];
IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 384);
```

instead of the second line, the connection with the module is not established and the error **no such host is Known** is displayed.
But if I want to connect to the IPs that are on my computer ("127.0.0.1"), everything is ok.

```
IPAddress ipAddress = Dns.GetHostEntry("127.0.0.1").AddressList[0];
IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 384);
```

Where is the problem and how can I fix it?
Thank

connect to ESP8266 wifi module.

Comment: tcpClient.Connected is dumb. You need to implement some keep-alive mechanism where the app sends some message to the ESP and the ESP responds.